# Cache SqlGroup.php expiration_date-value not Positive

Tags: civicrm-entity

Installed civicrm 5.20.1, Windows10, WP 5.3..
Install errors flag civicrm_cache.expiration_date, set in CRM/Utils/Cache/SqlGroup.php, in update and insert queries as FROM_UNIXTIME(%5) and FROM_UNIXTIME(%3) respectively, but no valid numeric arg values are supplied for expired_date like for created_date b/c $expires at line 133 isn't getting set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced line 133 -134 in SqlGroup.php with this:
$ttl1 = microtime(1);
$expires = strtotime($ttl1) + self::DEFAULT_TTL;